# How would you go about implementing the game reversi? (othello)

Tags: c++, graphics

I have been thinking about starting a side project at home to exercise my brain a bit.  [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) looks like a simply game, where mobility has a profound effect on game play.
It is at least a  step up from tic tac toe.  This would be a  single player against an AI of some sort.

I am thinking to try this in C++ on a PC.

What issues am I likely to run into?

What graphics library would you recommend?

What questions am I not smart enough to ask myself?

Comment: Are you talking about implementing a strategy for the reversi or simply let two players play on the computer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In overall, issues you will end up running onto will depend on you and your approaches. Friend tends to say that complex is simple from different perspective.

Choice of graphics library depends about what kind of game you are going to write? OpenGL is common choice in this kind of projects, but you could also use some GUI-library or directly just use windows' or xorg's own libraries. If you are going to do fancy, just use OpenGL.

Questions you ought ask:

Is C++ sensible choice for this project? Consider C and/or python as well. My answer to this would be that if you just want to write reversi, go python. But if you want to learn a low level language, do C first. C++ is an **extension** to C, therefore there's more to learn in there than there's in C. And to my judge, the more you have to learn onto C++ is not worth the effort.

How do you use the graphics library? If you are going to do fancy effects, go to the scene graph. Instead you can just render the reversi grid with buttons on it.

How ought you implement the UI, should you use the common UI concepts? Usual UI concepts (windowing, frames, buttons, menubars, dialogs) aren't so good as people think they are, there's lot of work in implementing them properly. Apply the scene graph for interpreting input and try different clever ways onto controlling the game. Avoid intro menus(they are dumb and useless work), use command line arguments for most configuration.

I yet give you some ideas to get you started:

Othello board is 8x8, 64 cells in overall. You can assign a byte per each cell, that makes it 64 bytes per each board state. It's 8 long ints, not very much at all! You can store the whole progress of the game and the player can't even notice it. Therefore it's advised to implement the othello board as an immutable structure which you copy always when you change a state. It will also help you later with your AI and implementing an 'undo' -feature.

Because one byte can store more information than just three states (EMPTY, BLACK, WHITE), I advice you will also provide two additional states (BLACK_ALLOWED, WHITE_ALLOWED, BOTH_ALLOWED). You can calculate these values while you copy the new state.

Algorithm for checking out where you can put a block, could go the board through one by one, then trace from empty cells to every direction for regex-patterns: B+W => W^, W+B => B^ This way you can encapsulate the game rules inside a simple interface that takes care of it all.

Comment: Bad advice. C++ is not just an extension, it's a different approach. The only thing they really share is some syntax, no more than C++ shares with javascript. C++ would give you a ton of benefits, like better memory management (through boost even), templates, objects, and so on that will help. It's harder to track a program state without an object to help, because you can't have independent data, it's either global or on the stack in C.

Answer (score 3):

Issues...

Well, just be sure when writing the strategy part of the game, not to simply do the move that gives you the most pieces.  You must also give weight to board position.  For example, given the opportunity to place a piece in a board corner should take priority over any other move (besides winning the game) as that piece can never be turned back over.  And, placing a piece adjacent to a corner spot is just about the worst move you can ever make (if the corner space is open).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, I would begin by getting a deep understanding of the gameplay and strategies, and the algorithms involved. This link may be useful to you, it describes basic Othello strategy and algorithms:

http://www.site-constructor.com/othello/Present/Basic_Strategy.html

Answer (score 2):

As the guys were suggesting my idea of telling you for thinking first for algorithms and the game logic. next answer for me was the graphics library, it depends on your target platform, programming language, framework etc. But as I suggest is using C# with Cairo 2D graphics library which you can achieve this using Mono framework (which then you can target all three major operating systems for your game to work) -> www.mono-project.org. Meanwhile I found this I think that and this kind of resource will help you: http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/misc/reversi/html/index.html. But if you finish this, you can try implementing Sudoku.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look into minimax with alpha-beta pruning if you write an AI to play against.  Your favorite search engine will have much to say on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

After you've taken a whack at the game logic yourself, go read chapter 18 of Peter Norvig's outstanding book [Paradigms of AI Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html). (Source code [here](http://norvig.com/paip/).) It has a rather short and extremely readable program that can kick just about any human's butt; you ought to learn a lot by comparing your solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of libraries out there but as far as I can think your game is going to need event and graphics libraries....and a sound library for more fun!
Allegro 5 is a best choice...Its an All in one library.
http://liballeg.org/
though It is written in C language you can create Object Oriented programs.

and A tutorial for this...

http://fixbyproximity.com/2d-game-development-course/

or you can use low level APIs like.. OpenGL for graphics.
OpenAL for sound.
glfw for events.

but OpenGL is a big deal because you have to create your own sprite sheet handler and all that 2d stuff.

Go with allegro...Complete your game and then go for OpenGL!

Answer (score 0):

Reversi should be a very simple game to implement. It is perfect to learn some basic algorithms of games theory (specifically min-max) during the implementation of the AI.

One thing to note on the AI is that it is perfectly possible to make a perfect AI for Reversi (one that always wins no matter the moves of its opponent). So on the strategy side, if your AI loses, you still have work to do :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is entirely true if the opponent is also an AI. Wikipedia says perfect play with this game is believed to end up to a draw.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it seems to me that with two AI players, one of the colors always wins (I don't know if it is white or black), by exactly one point.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a reversi game many years ago, when I was still at school. Its strategy was very simple, it just went for the maximum number of pieces, but weighted so it preferred the edges and particularly the corners and didn't like squares that risked giving away the corners.

This worked fairly well against people who hadn't yet worked out what it was doing, but once you had it was very easy to use its strategy against it. I'm not proud to say, however, that it beat me the first few times even though I'd written it!

A proper AI with a few moves of lookahead is far more complicated. Should be an interesting problem, but at the time I was more interested in the user interface.

Comment: Maximization leads directly to an early loss.